# Protractor: .click().then().. failing in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, protractor

I am running Protractor tests that all pass in Chrome, but one is failing in Firefox.

I am targeting a list of items and clicking on the first one which should bring you to the next page.

In Chrome this works fine, but in Firefox the page never changes and expectation fails.

Below are snippets of my code showing the page object and the test.

The page object:

```
this.items = element.all(by.repeater('item in items'));
```

The test:

```
it('should go to next page when selecting item', function () {
    pageObject.items.get(0).click().then(function () {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/my-next-page/);
    });
});
```

I've tried all kinds of workarounds but nothing seems to work. Anyone come across this issue?

Comment: On what kind of element are you clicking?

Comment: Can you try adding `browser.pause()` after click to see if the page is in fact hanging?

Comment: Julie, I added the pause() after the click. Firefox never changes page location and just sits there...

Comment: Have you tried this workaround: `browser.actions().mouseMove(element).mouseDown(element).mouseUp().perform();` ? to replace the click action. I had to use this on select options because of a FirefoxDriver known issue

Comment: I had this problem (only in firefox). The problem was that i wasn't clicking the innermost element with the ng-click associated. I only clicked on a parent and it seems it didn't get passed down for some reason. Hope helps someone.